# jquery Ajax Post success message not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

Have this simple $.ajax() post and the action is working - it does delete the giving task, however the success function isn't firing can you point me in the direction of why? with this said I have a similar post that works just fine once completed it it reloads the current page - same structure as this one??

```
//Delete clear_task
            $('i[name="delete"]').on('click',function(event) {
                var id = $(this).prop('id');
                if (event.target != event.currentTarget) {
                    return false;
                }

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "inc/edit-card.php",
                    data: {
                        id: id,
                        delete: 'delete'
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data,status) 
                     {
                        alert("Status: " +status );           
                     }

                });
                alert("Marked as Deleted!");
                        location.reload();
            })
```

The php

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $sql = "DELETE FROM `tasks` WHERE `id` = '$id'";

    if($query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
        return true;
    }else {
        echo "Something wrong with query".mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Ok removing a + sign after status got the location.reload working but it still don't fire the success alert?? why?

Comment: Try removing data from your success function?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `done` & `fail`:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "inc/edit-card.php",
                    data: {
                        id: id,
                        delete: 'delete'
                    },
                    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(response) {
 /** finished **/
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
 /** server returned error code **/
});
```

Also you should know when ajax request is requested your code outside of ajax request will execute immediately after it so it will reload your page and will not wait for ajax to finish, so you should call your reload inside of `done`.